# nginx and tomcat (with memcached session manager) config context cookies="false"

Tags: tomcat, cookies, nginx, jsessionid

I had some tomcat7 with memcached session manager, use nginx to proxy tomcats, it's ok.

But now, we need to pay on iphone safari, and access by a url with jsessionid.
So add cookies="false" to tomcat context.
Then we will lose session very access(with jsessionid in url).
But, when use nginx and one tomcat server, or directly access tomcat server, every thing is fine.

Why is happend?
Did anyone can solved this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Have you also tested with tomcat only, without nginx, do you experience the same in this case? What's your memcached session manager config, do you use sticky or non-sticky sessions?

Comment: I had tested with tomcat only, it's work fine.
memcached session manager config, used non-sticky sessions.

Comment: Ok, so with just tomcat it works, but proxied by nginx it doesn't work? Do you see any difference of requests that are hitting tomcat, e.g. in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to Martin Grotzke.
Tomcat log is fine.
I had found something in msm's log.

Nginx just proxy **only one tomcat** with config of cookies=“false”, 
first request, msm didn't backup session into memcached, 
next request with jsessionid in url, find session in tomcat, msm backup the session now.

If nginx proxy **two tomcats** with config of cookies=“false”,
 
first request, nginx proxy to TomcatA, login is ok, response sessionid(TomcatA), but msm 
didn't backup it into memcached,
next request, nginx proxy to TomcatB with sessionid(TomcatA) in url, there is not session in tomcat or memcached, so TomcatB create a new session,
third request, nginx proxy to TomcatA with sessionid(TomcatB's new session).
So, it always keep and share the session between two tomcat.

The resolve is remove the config of cookies=“false” in tomcat.

Comment: The issue then is that msm does not store the session in memcached, I submitted this as https://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/issues/detail?id=161

Comment: Can you show urls  with jsessionid? The jsessionid must be in front of any url params, so that http://localhost:8081/put?foo=baz works but http://localhost:8081/put?foo=baz;jsessionid=123456-n2 does not work. With the jsessionid correctly placed in the url I cannot reproduce the issue...